# Micronaut @Serdeable annotation processor is not recognizing the Lombok-generated code

Tags: maven, lombok, micronaut

I am implementing a REST API using Micronaut and Maven. I have a class CategoryDto annotated with Lombok's @Getter and @Serdeable. It appears that the Micronaut @Serdeable annotation processor is not recognizing the Lombok-generated code.

This the Rest controller :

```
@Controller("/categories")
public class CategoryController {

    @Get
    public List<CategoryDto> findAll() {
        return List.of(CategoryDto.of("1", "test"));
    }
```

```
@Serdeable
@Getter
public final class CategoryDto {

    private final String id;
    private final String name;

    public CategoryDto(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I have this maven-compile-plugin configuration :

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Uncomment to enable incremental compilation -->
                    <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>

                    <annotationProcessorPaths >
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                            <artifactId>micronaut-http-validation</artifactId>
                            <version>${micronaut.core.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>io.micronaut.serde</groupId>
                            <artifactId>micronaut-serde-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${micronaut.serialization.version}</version>
                            <exclusions>
                                <exclusion>
                                    <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>micronaut-inject</artifactId>
                                </exclusion>
                            </exclusions>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.group=io.maroodb</arg>
                        <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.module=app</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I'm using Lombok annotation processor before Micronaut, and I notice that the generated class has getters. However, when I try to fetch data from /categories, I get an empty list. Strangely, when I manually add getters, it works. Can someone assist me with this issue?

Comment: use java records instead of Lombok. Lombok causes trouble as you noticed

Comment: records don't cover all lombok features.

Comment: Do you need those features?

Comment: what features do you have in mind? are Pojos an alternative? Your example DTO doesn’t not use any feature that records do not provide. The Micronaut team strongly advises against using Lombok with Micronaut. Your actual problem is one of a long list of reasons.

Comment: My question is about how to make micronaut works well with lombok. Indeed in this simple example I can simply use records. But we can't extend class with records for example.